# minimal delay on waking monitor via GPIO/HDMI-CEC

Tags: gpio, sensor, pi-zero

I'm planning on creating a ["Magic Mirror"](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/magic-mirror/). I have already got the UI running to my likings and my Pi-zero is on its way.

My concern is that having the mirror powered on 24/7, is not really eco-friendly. So I have also ordered a motion sensor to attach to the GPIO pins.

I wanted to wire in the monitor's power button to another set of pins but was thinking of HDMI-CEC should the monitor I will be using support this.

However, switching on a monitor at work made me realize that there is quite some delay when powering on the monitor. Is there some way to "slumber" the monitor so that it uses next to no power and is comparable to switching off the monitor while still switching on quickly?

Comment: Sounds extremely device specific and, I suspect, difficult to nail down. Wake time isn't something that comes up often in TV/monitor manuals. What monitor are you using?

Comment: I haven't decided on what monitor I would use to hack up, might look at something 2nd hand.

Comment: Depending on your budget and the strictness of your requirement for a near-zero wake time, it might be easier to use a USB powered travel monitor and leave it running than it would be to try and persuade a standard monitor to wake faster. The exceedingly handsome example [here](https://medium.com/@maxbraun/my-bathroom-mirror-is-smarter-than-yours-94b21c6671ba#.sby0mzxc2) uses an ASUS MB MB168B+, but AOC did a few USB powered panels a few years ago you might be able to find on the cheap.

Comment: That link gives me hope! Now I don't have need to hack up an expensive monitor, but I can use something old or some alternative! thanks @goobering ... Though I realize now that the Pi will not be able to power the monitor from USB